# CakeDC/migrations - "Error: Plugin Migrate could not be found"

Tags: cakephp, cakedc, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.7

I am having problem to get Migrations plugin to load.

- I am running on Cakephp 2.7.7
- I have plugin loaded as instructed in bootstrap.php `CakePlugin::load('Migrations')`
- I have placed files to `app/Plugin/Migrations` folder as instructed

But I still get this error, while I try run migration.

```
SPT@FI-JKL-D-18 /c/xampp/htdocs/Emailer/app (master)
$ /c/xampp/htdocs/Emailer/lib/Cake/Console/cake Migrations.migrate generate

Error: Plugin Migrate could not be found.
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Emailer\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(227): CakePlugin::path('Migrate')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Emailer\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(549): App::path('Console/Command', 'Migrate')
#2 [internal function]: App::load('MigrateShell')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('MigrateShell')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Emailer\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(257): class_exists('MigrateShell')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Emailer\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(203): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('Migrations.migr...')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Emailer\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Emailer\lib\Cake\Console\cake.php(54): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#8 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've got the syntax wrong.

Instead of

```
cake Migrations.migrate generate
```

try running

```
cake Migrations.migration generate
```

See the [examples in the CakeDC/migrations](https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Examples.md) plugin.

Comment: Oh my god, I totally facepalmed myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am using CakePHP 4. I have faced same problem. I have solved the issue running the command `cake migrations migrate`. It has worked for me.